# How to store HTML file input into SQL database as a blob type

Tags: html, sql, plsql

I am designing a website and have forms that the user can submit and it will store their form input data in a sql server. I am able to store text, number, and date, fields, but I am trying to store the user's file input into a blob data type.

I am accepting the users data as an input parameter for a procedure.

I have a form with many inputs, here are a couple.

```
<label for="cont_file" class="item_7"> Contract File: </label>
<input type="file" id="cont_file" name="cont_file" accept="image/*,.pdf,.jpeg,.doc,.docx"></input>

  <label for="it_con" class="item_8"> IT Contact: </label> 
<input type="text" id="it_con" name="it_con" required></input>
```

Once the user hits submit, it sends the info to a plsql procedure

```
procedure handle_contract(cont_file in blob := 'cont_file', it_con in varchar2 := 'it_con)
```

yet this keep giving me incompatible type errors on the cont_file variable. Any ideas on how to do this better would be much appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the HTML text, and if so can't you store it in a `CLOB`? Also, by *a sql server* do you mean an Oracle database?

Comment: I do mean oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your input data in a CLOB field. In handle_contract procedure you can use TO_CLOB function for converting cont_file parameter into CLOB data. Then there should not be problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure handle_contract(cont_file in blob := 'cont_file', it_con in varchar2 := 'it_con)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.TABLE( clob_field)
SELECT TO_CLOB(cont_file) FROM DUAL;

COMMIT;
END;
```